# Cognito user attributes breaks Amplify Storage component

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, federated

Backend: `Cognito` and `S3`.

Frontend: `React` with `aws-amplify`.

Basic functionality works. I now need fine grained access control over directories in the S3 bucket. e.g. `user-test` can only access files in `s3::my-bucket/user-test`

The plan is to add user attributes ([Principal Tag Attributes for access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-attributes-for-access-control-policy-example.html)) to the Federated Identity, which can be referenced on a per user basis in the Authorising Policy. However, the Amplify Storage component(s) break with ANY user attributes.

Any Storage request (list, get, put... ) returns this error:

```
AWSS3Provider - get signed url error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')
    at isEmptyData (isEmptyData.ts:11)
    at Sha256.update (webCryptoSha256.ts:32)
    at Sha256.update (crossPlatformSha256.ts:23)
    at hmac (credentialDerivation.ts:69)
    at credentialDerivation.ts:39
    at step (tslib.es6.js:100)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
    at tslib.es6.js:74
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:70)
    at getSigningKey (credentialDerivation.ts:37)
    at SignatureV4.getSigningKey (SignatureV4.ts:307)
    at SignatureV4.<anonymous> (SignatureV4.ts:153)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:100)
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
    at fulfilled (tslib.es6.js:71)
```

I suspect my use case is beyond the scope of `aws-amplify`, what should I use instead?